# Cross-Site Scripting Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

Fortify identified the following line within my ASP.NET code as being a critical issue.  How could I resolve this Cross-Site Scripting issue found?

```
<asp:Literal ID="litParticipants" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Participants") %>' />
```

The following will work as a fix for a label.  However, I'm unsure of the fix for a literal???

```
Server.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("System").ToString())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4.5 you should use the AntiXssEncoder class to HTML encode the output (System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HTMLEncode()). Your above code would look like:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litParticipants" runat="server" Text='<%# AntiXssEncoder.HTMLEncode(Eval("Participants")) %>' />
```

You can also set the default encoder for the app to the AntiXSSEncoder in web.config like so:

```
<httpRuntime ...encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

If you're using an older version of .NET, you'll need to grab the Microsoft Web Protection Library.

Be careful when using Server.HTMLEncode(), it doesn't encode all of the characters. You need to use a better encoder, such as the AntiXSS Encoder or the Enterprise Security API (ESAPI) from OWASP.

Comment: Eric, Thank you, but this won't work because the special characters from the HTML are being displayed.

Comment: The characters will still be displayed, but will be in their HTML equivalent form. The point it to make executable code into non-executable code. <script> becomes &lt;script&gt;. That will prevent the injected code from being executed by the browser.

Comment: Eric, Thank you again for your help.  This did not help me so much a few weeks ago.  However, your answer helped me tremendously in the last few days.  I had to do a lot of research regarding Cross Site Scripting to understand Cross Site Scripting and your answer.  & I also did a .NET upgrade.  I truly appreciate your help.